# "They have a house of their own" or "They have their own house"?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct if I say "They have their own house" or is the variant "They have a house of their own" the only correct in this case?And if I change "have" into "live"(they live in their own house/they live in a house of their own), will somwthing change from the point of view of grammar and "correctness" or are these sentences both correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["They have their own house" or "They have a house of their own"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232298/they-have-their-own-house-or-they-have-a-house-of-their-own)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones There is no answer under that question. Making the matter worse is that that question was also asked by the same OP.

Comment: You have already asked this same question on this site and received no answer. We understand you are looking for an answer, but please don't ask the same question repeatedly. You can edit your old question to make it clearer and easier for us to answer.